# Better way of comparing Files?

Tags: c#, performance, foreach

I have this method that receives an IEnumerable of Strings which are basically a list of Files(PDF), and then inside the method I get an array of String and fill it with files from a different location(TIFF), the main idea of this method is to match all the Files from the received list to a File inside the other list I fill inside the method and to make sure that there's a corresponding TIFF File for every PDF. Right now the method works but I just wanted to know if theres a better way of doing all this.

```
    private bool MatchingFiles(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        var outputFiles = Directory.GetFiles(TifOutput, "*.tif");
        bool foundmatch = true;
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string[] strArray = file.Split('\\');

            string fileName = strArray[strArray.Length - 1].Replace("PDF", "");
            bool filematch = false;
            foreach (string outputFile in outputFiles)
            {
                if (outputFile.Contains(fileName))
                {
                    filematch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!filematch)
            {
                LogMessage(string.Format("File Not Available Yet: {0}", fileName), Level.Info, null);
                foundmatch = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return foundmatch;
    }
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that will help me :)!

Comment: Use the `Path` namespace...it'll make your life easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Path.GetfileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) to get File Names only and then use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) like:

You can do:

```
return files.Select(r => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(r))
            .Except(outputFiles.Select(r => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(r)))
            .Any();
```

Or

```
return files.Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
            .Except(outputFiles.Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension))
            .Any();
```

Comment: So any of those will do exactly the same as I'm doing on the original method?

Comment: @AlonsoQuesada, This code will return a bool indicating if there are any difference between files and outputfiles based on just file name.

Comment: @AlonsoQuesada, so yes it would the same thing. I wrote my answer based on `the main idea of this method is to match all the Files from the received list to a File inside the other list I fill inside the method and to make sure that there's a corresponding TIFF File for every PDF`